# Why is the 0 key last on the QWERTY keyboard layout and scan codes, but the first in ASCII and EBCDIC?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ascii, qwerty

In ASCII, 0 is first, before 1.
In EBCDIC, 0 is still first, before 1.

This enables computations and conversions between codes and digits, simply by subtracting "0".
Eg: "0" - "0" (ASCII or EBCDIC) = 0 (Digit)
& : "9" - "0" (ASCII or EBCDIC) = 9 (Digit)
Moreover, this is the Natural Universal Sequence.

In the QWERTY Keyboard layout, 0 comes last, after 9.
The Scan codes are similar, with 0 coming last, after 9.
What is the advantage of this layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first QWERTY layout is depicted in Sholes's 1878 patent:

[image]

Many early typewriter keyboards then did not have any key to the left
of the "2", since a typist who needed to type the digit below that could
use an uppercase `I` or lowercase `l` for the purpose.

Typewriter keyboards which used a shift key for uppercase did generally
include a "0". However, since typing an uppercase "O" as an alternative
would require using the shift key, putting the zero to the right of the
nine meant that it could be in the same place on keyboards which include
a "1" as on keys which do not.

Another possible factor influencing the design is a telephone dial.
On a rotary telephone in many countries, dialing a "1"
will briefly interrupt the line current once;
dialing a "2" will briefly interrupt the line current twice.
Having "0" interrupt the line current zero times would be
impractical, so instead it interrupts the line current ten times.
With that technical logic, it's much easier for the dial to be
arranged "1234567890".

[image]

Sources:

- [Wikipedia QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY)
- [Wikipedia Telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone)
- [Why is the 0 next to 9, not next to 1?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/why-is-the-0-next-to-9-not-next-to-1)

Comment: +1 , I got to know more about the history of type writers and keyboards through this ! But this is only half of my question .... While the early type writers may have put the 0 in the end, the discrepancy in keyboard scan codes is unanswered. Surely, the electronics in the keyboard could easily have put the scan codes in order like ASCII or EBCDIC ....

Comment: This was decided much before my time, but it's only logical to assume that the engineers were influenced by the layout of the keyboard they were implementing, rather than by numerical considerations. Also, as the `0` key was a later addition to keyboards, it's logical that it doesn't come in sequence. Perhaps also the previous code to `1` was already taken.

Comment: I have Partial Answers to the other half : Hardware keyboard scan codes are mostly based on the Position on the keyboard Matrix Electrical Circuitry, and a lookup table converts the Electrical Signals to keyboard scan codes; Decision on keyboard scan codes is based on the Position and the Electrical Matrix Circuitry; Decision is not based on the meaning of the key. Higher layers can convert this in Software to more meaningful orders like ASCII or EBCDIC .... [[ http://www.philipstorr.id.au/pcbook/book3/scancode.htm ]] & [[ http://www.philipstorr.id.au/pcbook/book3/keyboard.htm ]]